# What is the meaning of this phrase from Money Heist theme?

Tags: meaning, phrase-meaning

What is the meaning of the phrase, "Lost my time, my life is going on..?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. One line questions are discouraged on this site. Please consider editing to give more explanations and provide the research you've made while trying to answer this question yourself. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Song lyrics, like poetry, don't always make complete grammatical sense but they do convey ideas.

"Lost my time" suggests that time has passed you by - that you have missed out on something, perhaps wasted your time, or your life.

"My life is going on" means that your life is moving forward, progressing. So, along with the previous statement, it seems to suggest that the first person in the song has lost time in the past, but is trying to move forward with their life rather than dwell in the past. That certainly seems to be supported by the line "*I will be so strong, looking for a new version of myself*" that also appears in the full version of the song.

Comment: Thank you Astralbee! 